# Minimal polynomial of $\alpha+i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

$\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
 The task is to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+i$

I have shown that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+i)=\mathbb{Q}(i,\alpha)$ and that $|\mathbb{Q}(i,\alpha):\mathbb{Q}|=6$. So I'm expecting this to be a degree $6$ polynomial. I have tried getting various powers of $\alpha+i$.

Since complex conjugation is a field automorphism and maps roots to roots, I know that $\alpha-i$ must also be a root.

I do no know what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the polynomial that has the root $\beta=\alpha+ i$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset\Bbb{R}$ in-terms of $\alpha.$

Then use the fact that $\alpha^3-\alpha+1=0$ to get rid of $\alpha$ in previous polynomial.

OR:
Note that $$(\beta-i)^3-(\beta-i)+1=0$$

Comment: $\alpha+i$ is a root of $(x-\alpha)^2+1=x^2-2\alpha x+\alpha^2+1$, how exactly do I proceed?

Comment: I add bit more to my answer. The second approach would be more efficient.

Comment: I actually had the first line of the second approach written down pages ago, it leads me to $\beta^3-3i\beta^2-2\beta+1=0$

Comment: Then move $-3i\beta^2$ term in to RHS and square both sides :) Do not forget to make sure that the resulting equation is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}.$

Comment: Yeah.... I'm a week into my finals and my brain is just so fried, it refuses to see simple things, thank you

Comment: Good luck for your exam :)

Comment: I suspicious that your computations are incorrect. As I think it should be $\beta^3-3i \beta^2-4\beta+(1+2i)=0.$

Comment: Yes you are correct, the method still works out though

Answer (score 1):

This is the systematic approach (why am I doing this):

Pick $\Bbb Q$-basis $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, i, i\alpha, i\alpha^2\}$. Note that $\alpha^3 = \alpha - 1$.

Look at the map $\varphi : \Bbb Q(\alpha, i) \to \Bbb Q(\alpha, i)$ sending $x$ to $(\alpha + i)x$.

- $\varphi(1) = \alpha + i$
- $\varphi(\alpha) = \alpha^2 + i\alpha$
- $\varphi(\alpha^2) = \alpha^3 + i\alpha^2 = -1 + \alpha + i\alpha^2$
- $\varphi(i) = -1 + i\alpha$
- $\varphi(i\alpha) = -\alpha + i\alpha^2$
- $\varphi(i\alpha^2) = -\alpha^2 + i\alpha^3 = -\alpha^2 - i + i\alpha$

So the matrix representing the map is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
-1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\
-1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 & -1 & -1 &  1 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$$

whose characteristic polynomial is $t^6 + t^4 + 2t^3 + 4t^2 - 8t + 5$ (thanks, Wolfram Alpha), which is also the minimal polynomial of $\alpha + i$ thanks to Cayley-Hamilton.

Answer (score 1):

My different systematic approach:

If $\alpha$ is a root of the $\Bbb Q$-irreducible polynomial $f(X)$, then of $f$ is $\alpha$’s minimal (and characteristic) polynomial. Now $f(X)$ is still irreducible over $k=\Bbb Q(i)$, because $k$ contains no cubic quantities and therefore $f$ has no roots there. It follows that $f(X-i)$ is also $k$-irreducible, and is therefore the $k$-minimal polynomial for $\alpha+i$. Mutiply this by its conjugate to get $g(X)=f(X-i)(f(X+i)\in\Bbb Q[X]$. It is a $\Bbb Q$-polynomial of the right degree, with $\alpha+i$ as a root. And:

By an easy hand computation, we find that $g=X^6 + X^4 +2X^3 + 4X^2 - 8X+5$, same as @KennyLau got, but without prayer or supplication to Wolfram.

Comment: This has to be the least computationally expensive way of doing it